# Accessing this from inside object's function without callbacks?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to call an object (this) (in the example it's o) from within its children.

As shown in the example: I have 10 instances of o inside wrap.instances and I want to call one of these instances from DOM call, via wrap. When I call a var t (this) is set to a() -- how can I set the scope to o instead of its function?

Thanks!

```
//DOM call
$('#app').on('click', '[call]', function(e) {
    wrap.call($(this).attr('call'));
});

//Wrap
const wrap = {
    instances: {},
    call: function(k) {
        this.instances[k].fn.a();
    }
}

//Instance o
let o = {
    fn: {
        a: function() {
            var t = this; //This is a, not o
            t.fn.b(); //Error, since scope is function a
        },
        b: function() { }
    }
};
```

Comment: Why not just change the call to `t.b()` rather than `t.fn.b()`?

Comment: I don't think it would make a difference, would it? Since I can't access the correct t in the first place

Comment: `this` is `fn`, not `a`

Comment: `this` is actually `fn`, not `a` or `window`

Comment: `this.instances[k].fn.a();` will call `a` with a calling context of `this.instances[k].fn`, right? So just access `this.b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

`this.instances[k].fn.a.apply(this.instances[k]);`

Comment: Yeah, this works, no idea why I was trying to call .apply on function call, instead of function reference.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could just `.bind` the function to `o`:

```
let o = {};
Object.assign(o, {
  fn: {
    a: function() {
        var t = this; // this is o
        t.fn.b(); // no error
    }.bind(o),
    b: function() { }.bind(o)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your calling context is `fn`, another option would be to change the `a` function to call `this.b` (so as to refer to `fn.b`) rather than `this.fn.b` (which would require a non-standard calling context of `o`):

```
let o = {
    fn: {
        a: function() {
            this.b();
        },
        b: function() { }
    }
};
```

Comment: Just as a followup; I could not use this method due to the complexity/hierarchy of the object, perhaps the example I've given in the OP wasn't really the best